# osm2pgsql can reimport with multi-geometry once imported full OSM data without starting from zero?

Tags: osm2pgsql, multi-geometry

Well, I executed the `osm2pgsql` command without the `-G` param which is intended to do a multi geometry search: https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#geometry-processing

But I already did: `sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -s -C16G --flat-nodes=/tmp/osm-cache.bin --number-processes=8 /osmpbf/planet.osm.pbf -d osm`

Can I do something else in order to create multi geometry relations without starting from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. The easiest way is to run the import again, but one option would be to find the cases in the polygon table where there are multiple rows with the same ID, and use PostGIS to turn this into a `MULTIPOLYGON`.

You could generate a new table with these geometries with

```sql
CREATE TABLE planet_osm_polygon_merged AS
SELECT
    osm_id, amenity, -- ... add the rest of columns in your style file
    ST_Collect(way), SUM(way_area)
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE osm_id < 0
GROUP BY osm_id, amenity --, ... add the rest of columns in your style file
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can then inspect the results in the table, delete the rows from the existing `planet_osm_polygon` table that are in the `planet_osm_polygon_merged` table, and insert the rows from the `planet_osm_polygon_merged` to the `planet_osm_polygon` table.

I note that you did a `--slim` import without `--drop`, so you've created a database you can keep up to date with diffs. Be sure to stop updates while doing this process. If you don't plan to do updates, I recommend dropping the `planet_osm_rels`, `planet_osm_ways` and `planet_osm_nodes` tables to save space and using `--drop` next time you import.

Overall, I do not recommend this method, but instead recommend reimporting with the correct options as documented in the style you are using, and suggesting to the style that they use lua transforms or the flex backend instead of the dated osm2pgsql "C transforms".